# Shouldn't the Content in ForEach conform to View

Tags: generics, swiftui

Shouldn't the `Content` in `ForEach` conform to `View` ?

Here ForEach is defined as

[image]

Now I was really certain that it should be declared as:

```
struct ForEach<Data, ID, Content> where Data: RandomAccessCollection, ID: Hashable,    Content: View
```

So I kept searching and found this:

[image]

So now my question is:

**Can Generics be defined somewhere else in the pipeline or is this a mistake in the documentation**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an extension that makes generic `ForEach` is-a `View` with content as views

```
@available(iOS 13.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
extension ForEach : View where Content : View {

    /// The type of view representing the body of this view.
    ///
    /// When you create a custom view, Swift infers this type from your
    /// implementation of the required `body` property.
    public typealias Body = Never
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no mistake, both are correct, when you want use `ForEach` you have to take decision that you are going use **Data** or **Range**! If you want use **Data**, then you have to provide ID that passed Hashable protocol, but when you decide that you better use **Range**, in this case you have use Int or `\.self`

Also in both case you have to pass **View/some View** as Content to your `ForEach`.

and you can use both world together with enumerated method.

Comment: Yes, but whether it is data or range, they still need to be supplied with `Content` and that's what I'm wondering about. Why isn't the type restraint declared for it like it was for `Data` and `ID` in the struct declaration

Comment: As I said and you know, in both case you have to give **View/some View** as content, the deference is here: when you use Data, then you have access to item itself, or when you use Int, then you have access to index, and also you can get access both with enumerated method.

Comment: But before we even get to which data is being passed.. why isn't this on the struct declaration line: `Content: View`

Maybe I'm not understanding your point

Comment: there is so simple connection, in both method we have to give Content to ForEach, so there is no escaping of that, the deference is here: SwiftUI gave us 2 way, that we can use those ways to feed input data to our Content, that input data could be Data from item of items of array, or index, which we could read data of an element of array to make input data to our Content, so simple.